# Golang generic return type on a method

Tags: go

I'm new to golang, and I'm struggling to see how I can get some generic behavior on a method.

```golang
func (s *service) getCars(filter Filter) ([]car, error){
    var err error
    var cars []car
    switch filter {
    case filter.Toyota:
        cars, err = s.dbClient.getToyotas()
    case filter.Honda:
        cars, err = s.dbClient.getHondas()
    }
    return cars, nil
}
```

The objects returned from s.dbClient.getToyotas() and s.dbClient.getHondas() are data structs with the same fields, but have different types. I should note these returned structs are auto generated, so I don't have the ability to alter them.

It looks like go interfaces only allow methods, and not data fields, so I don't if it's even possible to define a `car` type that can be used as the return type. I looked at generics as well, but it seems that generics are not allowed on struct methods.

What's the idiomatic way of doing something like this in go?

Comment: Golang can do inheritance by embedded struct or by interface or both. Since your structs share common data fields, see [Inheritance in GO using interface + struct](https://golangbyexample.com/inheritance-go-interface-struct/). If they didn't you'd write a car interface, have both Honda and Toyota implement it, and define functions to work with anything that satisfies the car interface.

Comment: If they have the same fields, do they need different types? Also you should return your error. `return cars, err`.

Comment: @Schwern thanks for the link to the article. They are different types because they are auto generated structs created from a database schema file.

Comment: @Schwern it looks like the inheritance in go using interface + struct works by creating accessor methods on the struct that expose internal data. I don't this works for me here given that I don't have control over the structs returned by `getToyotas` or `getHondas`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining a common interface is the idiomatic way to go.

Access to fields can be "modeled" by defining accessor methods on interface and then implementing those on specific structs.

In fact, it is a better solution as those methods can do more than simple access to internal, private variables. For example, they can have lazy initialization or cached access built in. Each struct can have unique implementation or you can have a base struct with default one.

Comment: I should have noted this in the question, but I am not able to edit the structs that are returned by `s.dbClient.getToyotas()` or `s.dbClient.getHondas()`.  These are auto generated based on database schema file, and so I'm not able to define accessor methods on them.

Comment: Then common ancestor struct would not work either, since you don't control the definition of those structs. What is common about those? Can you post them?

Comment: The car example I'm using is contrived for simplicity, but you can think about these structs as pure data structs. The are auto generated by [sqlc](https://github.com/kyleconroy/sqlc), and each field corresponds to a column in the table that I'm querying. `getToyotas` and `getHondas` have the same sql select statement, and therefore the same exact fields in the struct, just different types.

Comment: For the sake of the contrived example, `type HondaRow struct { color string; model int}` and `type ToyotaRow struct {color string; model int}`

Comment: @sgonzalez You should not have to edit the structs to implement an interface. You would define an interface with, for example, getColor and getModel and then write implementations for HondaRow and ToyotaRow. Or define a Car struct and methods to load HondaRow and ToyotaRow data into a Car; that's possibly better than using the raw row returned from SQL.

Comment: Agree, methods for those generated structs can be defined in separate file.. as long as that file is placed in the same package.
So you can define interface and implement its methods  - in Go interfaces are implemented implicitly

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I think this is the right solution. It seems though that since I'm returning a slice ([]car), I actually can't directly just return ([]ToyotaRow or []HondaRow). Instead, I have to loop through the results and manually convert. Do you know if there is any workaround for this? It seems very inefficient to have to loop through results each time, especially if what's being returned from the db is large.

Comment: If you want the `ToyotaRow` and `HondaRow` to implement the same `Car` interface, they just have to implement all the methods the same interface. 
Typecasting arrays of structs to `Car` would not work unfortunately - you'd have to loop through array and add individual items to array of `Car`. It is slightly inefficient, but, to me, the benefits outweigh those inefficiencies.